# (Unreal) Creating 3D tiles (cubes) for the scenery of a 2.5D rpg (similar to Pokemon Gen IV and V)

Tags: tilemap, maps, rpg, unreal, 2.5d

I developed a concept for a college class and I think it has enough potential to actually become a game. The visuals will be similar to games like Pokémon Black and Octopath Traveler as in the characters are 2D pixelated sprites travelling through a 3D world with a fixed top down camera. I already made the character blueprint (the movement and camera position) in Unreal and it's working close to what it's intended but now I'm having trouble making the scenery!

I would love to learn a pratical way to make a "blocky" world that fits the 2D pixelated sprites aesthetic. Even better, a way to make 3d tiles that make that my Paper2D char will travel only in 4 directions and from tile to tile (identical to old DS pokémon games).

I have a lead from the Octopath dev's presentation where they show this custom tool to place blocks in the world (GIF bellow) but i have yet to find a way to develop something similar. I thought of Minecraft and how it has a blocky world where the player can place the blocks in it but I don't know if that's quite it.

[Octopath MapEditor GIF](https://i.imgur.com/cprzoWH.gifv)

Comment: This type of model is usually described as "voxel art" and you can make it in tools like [MagicaVoxel](https://ephtracy.github.io/).

Comment: Ohhh i see! I didn't know that was the name! Thank you so much for that info, it is very helpful for sure. Do you think i should close the question? I mean, i still would like to know if anyone knows how to setup this tile based 4 direction movement in unreal (like, my character can move 8 directions and it feels like its ice skating, i really don't like it), but i guess i should make a more specific question about that.

Comment: You can edit this question to ask about the that specific issue

Comment: Do you have a link to the full presentation the gif comes from?